# ASPX WebMethod seems not to be caching results

Tags: asp.net, caching, webmethod

I need a couple of methods on an aspx page to cache their results to avoid lots of going to the database. I added the relevant WebMethod attributes but although the code runs, the methods are not caching their results.

The trouble is, I'm a) not sure whether this can be done in the first place, and if it is then b) whether there is something particular you need to do on aspx pages to make this work.

Does a page's cached results only last the lifetime of the page?  I need the data to be cached across many page requests.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Cache the response objects in your web service.

[http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/6hbbsfk6(v=VS.100).aspx](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/6hbbsfk6%28v=VS.100%29.aspx)

EDIT:

This looks promising:
http://support.microsoft.com/kb/318299

Comment: Not quite what I had in mind - I want the ease of caching a webservice gives you, in an aspx page.  Thanks for the quick response however.

Comment: Remember, this is not an asmx file, it's an aspx page, so it's not a web service, but a page in the site.